# Reading a file with FileStream and FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING

Tags: c#, windows

A little background:  I've been experimenting with using the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flag when doing IO with large files.  We're trying to reduce the load on the cache manager in the hope that with background IO, we'll reduce the impact of our app on user machines.  Performance is not an issue.  Being behind the scenes as much as possible is a big issue.  I have a close-to-working wrapper for doing unbuffered IO but I ran into a strange issue.  I get this error when I call Read with an offset that is not a multiple of 4.

> Handle does not support synchronous operations. The parameters to the FileStream constructor may need to be changed to indicate that the handle was opened asynchronously (that is, it was opened explicitly for overlapped I/O).

Why does this happen?  And is doesn't this message contradict itself? If I add the Asynchronous file option I get an IOException(The parameter is incorrect.)

I guess the real question is what do these requirements, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, have to do with these multiples of 4.

Here is the code that demonstrates the issue:

```
FileOptions FileFlagNoBuffering = (FileOptions)0x20000000;
int MinSectorSize = 512;
byte[] buffer = new byte[MinSectorSize * 2];
int i = 0;
while (i < MinSectorSize)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"<some file>", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 8, FileFlagNoBuffering | FileOptions.Asynchronous))
        {
            fs.Read(buffer, i, MinSectorSize);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
    catch { }
    i++;
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: There's probably a reason why that flag was not included in the FileOptions enum.  Furthermore, there are [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you must adhere to when using that flag; FileStream probably doesn't follow them since it doesn't expose that flag.

Comment: Yes but there is a reason it exists in the underlying Win32 API. I know there are requirements. I've read that link many times.  FileStream will follow them if you tell it to. What does "File access buffer addresses for read and write operations should be physical sector-aligned, which means aligned on addresses in memory that are integer multiples of the volume's physical sector size" have to do with 4?

Comment: The value 4 is relevant here because that's the alignment that the CLR guarantees for managed object addresses in a 32-bit processes.  Otherwise the magic number for a 32-bit operating system.  This has otherwise little to do with what the disk driver puts up with.  You get sector alignment by allocating the memory in unmanaged memory, Marshal.AllocHGlobal(), over-allocating and adjusting the start address to get alignment.  Otherwise the reason this option is not exposed in the framework.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant .  If you add your comment as an answer I will mark it as the answer so you get credit.

Comment: Um, you can't just make up a flag (`FileFlagNoBuffering`) and expect `FileStream` to magically support it. Instead, `FileStream` most likely ignored your bogus flag and used a buffer anyway, which is why it seems to work when the offset is zero. (The internal buffer happens to be properly aligned.)

Comment: You really ought to play more with .NET.  Classes like FileStream are *very* thin wrappers.  It explicitly allows FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, no exception.

Comment: @HansPassant I find no documentation where it says that `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` is supported as a `FileOption`, though you're right - it's being passed through to `CreateFile`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, the documented requirement is that the memory address for a read or write must be a multiple of the physical sector size.  In your code, you've allowed the address of the byte array to be randomly chosen (hence unlikely to be a multiple of the physical sector size) and then you're adding an offset.

The behaviour you're observing is that the call works if the offset is a multiple of 4.  It is likely that the byte array is aligned to a 4-byte boundary, so the call is working if the memory address is a multiple of 4.

Therefore, your question can be rewritten like this: why is the read working when the memory address is a multiple of 4, when the documentation says it has to be a multiple of 512?

The answer is that the documentation doesn't make any specific guarantees about what happens if you break the rules.  It may happen that the call works anyway.  It may happen that the call works anyway, but only in September on even-numbered years.  It may happen that the call works anyway, but only if the memory address is a multiple of 4.  (It is likely that this depends on the specific hardware and device drivers involved in the read operation.  Just because it works on your machine doesn't mean it will work on anybody else's.)

It probably isn't a good idea to use `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` with `FileStream` in the first place, because I doubt that `FileStream` actually guarantees that it will pass the address you give it unmodified to the underlying `ReadFile` call.  Instead, use P/Invoke to call the underlying API functions directly.  You may also need to allocate your memory this way, because I don't know whether .NET provides any way to allocate memory with a particular alignment or not.

Comment: Wouldn't things break horribly all over FileStream if it didn't pass the actual address of the byte array to the underlying Readfile?  I have had no problems with my approach so far except when trying to use a non-zero offset.

Comment: It might be the case that under some circumstances FileStream reads the data into a temporary buffer of its own before copying it to your array.  I'm guessing it doesn't, but you don't want to depend on guessing if you can help it.  More importantly, you should be following the documented requirement of aligning to the physical sector size, *even if it seems to work when you don't*.

Answer (score 2):

Just call CreateFile directly with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING and then close it before opening with FileStream to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I recommend this answer to be upvoted.  I've tested it, and it works just like @user2882190 indicates.

Answer (score 0):

I used the original question and the answer by Harry Johnston and came up with the following (requires .NET 6+)

- 512 is sector size
- size needs to be a multiple of sector size
- Buffer size needs to be 0 so that the buffer that we created is used in ReadFile

This code seems to work, but it can change if FileStream implementation changes. For example, if buffering is inserted into the mix.

```
FileOptions FileFlagNoBuffering = (FileOptions)0x20000000;

var size = 256 * 1024;
var buf = NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc((uint)size, 512);
var bufSpan = new Span<byte>(buf, size);
using var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 0, FileFlagNoBuffering | FileOptions.Asynchronous);
var readBytes = stream.Read(bufSpan);
```