# Windows API CreateFile: "Invalid parameter" exception with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING

Tags: c#, winapi, mono, unity-game-engine, pinvoke

I'm using the CreateFile Windows API in C# (Unity, .NET 2.0 via Mono) to write a file to disk. I'm doing so in order to use both FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING and FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, in order to attain the following behavior as stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

"If FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH and FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING are both specified, so that system caching is not in effect, then the data is immediately flushed to disk without going through the Windows system cache. The operating system also requests a write-through of the hard disk's local hardware cache to persistent media."

I am able to write the file, and I can set FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH successfully. However, if I set FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, with or without FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, I get an exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Invalid parameter
```

In this case, a blank file is created. If I just use FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH or no flags, the file is created properly, with the desired contents. Here is the code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        string FileName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare dwShareMode,
        IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
        uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    private const uint FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = 0x20000000;
    private const uint FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH = 0x80000000;

    private const int SECTOR_SIZE = 512;

    private static void WriteToDisk( string fileNameToWrite, string stringToWrite )
    {
        SafeFileHandle fileHandle = CreateFile(FileName: fileNameToWrite,
                                    dwDesiredAccess: FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                                    dwShareMode: FileShare.None,
                                    lpSecurityAttributes: IntPtr.Zero,
                                    dwCreationDisposition: FileMode.Create,
                                    dwFlagsAndAttributes: FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH,
                                    hTemplateFile: IntPtr.Zero);

        try
        {
            FileStream newStream = new FileStream (fileHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, SECTOR_SIZE, true);
            StreamWriter newStreamWriter = new StreamWriter (newStream);
            newStreamWriter.WriteLine (stringToWrite);
            newStreamWriter.Close ();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Error writing backup file to disk: " + ex.ToString ());
        }
    }
```

So my question is, what do I need to change here in order to use both of these flags together? The only requirement I see is my file access size (which is correct for my disk).

Comment: Perhaps your problem might be related to this one (check out its answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377914/reading-a-file-with-filestream-and-file-flag-no-buffering

Comment: Short version: FileStream and FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING can't be expected to play well together.