# c# - FileStream with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING , where "the remaining data after last read" is or go?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, filestream

Code :

```
 FileOptions nocash = (FileOptions)0x20000000;
    FileStream fs;
    byte[] data;
    int x = 32 * 1024;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\iP\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication32\ConsoleApplication32\bin\Debug\hello.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, x, FileOptions.Asynchronous|nocash);

        data = new byte[x];


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int i = 0;
        double pos = 0;



        try
        {


            while (await fs.ReadAsync(data, 0, x) > 0)
            {
                i++;
                if (i == 27013)
                {
                    pos = fs.Length - fs.Position;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            textBox2.AppendText(pos.ToString()+"    "+fs.Position.ToString() + "    "+fs.Length.ToString() );



        }
}
```

i am trying to read from file with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING

1- i set internal buffer to 32kb

2- i set the array which i will read in it , it is lengh = 32kb = buffer lengh

i get error " the parametr is incorrect " in last read in file

- 27013 is  i 's value in last turn in while loop before the exception " the parametr is incorrect "
- pos = 19123 -> the remaining bytes in the file

but after the exception fs.position and fs.lengh has same value contrary pos's value

my question is : where is the data which is between pos and fs.position going ??

or there are a way to read the remaining bytes in the file ??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

<del>You are trying to read with the length of the 32k buffer, despite the file itself may be much more less. You hit the exception because it is the end of file and you cannot read any further. That's why the fs.pos and fs.length are the same in your case.</del>  
<del>**Solution:**</del>
<del>Change variable `x` value to `fs.Length`</del>
<del>or</del>
<del>`data = new byte[fs.Length];`</del>
<del>`...`</del>
<del>`while (await fs.ReadAsync(data, 0, fs.Length) > 0)`</del>

**Update**
Actually the error is the following:

> System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_CustomAttributes cannot be called in
>   this context.

It turns out the flag FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING is not supported. Check here for more info:
[Reading a file with FileStream and FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377914/reading-a-file-with-filestream-and-file-flag-no-buffering)

Comment: yeah yeah i know that , but i am using FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING which has requirements to read data with it ,one of these requirements " i must read numbers of bytes that is multiple of the volume sector size , check this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering) , so i cant but any number except for example (512, 1024,2048,4096)